# Providing access permissions to 2 git repositories inside single git instance

Tags: git

I have two git repositories in one single git instance and need one set of users to access one repository and another set of users to access second repository.

How can I create a group, and add users to it and provide them permissions to access the git repository.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in windows machine using git bash

Comment: This sounds more like "2 projects within a single git instance" NOT really "2 git repositories inside single git instance"

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my other answer (two repositories), if groups is really what you want, you could use gitosis.

More at http://shapeshed.com/setting_up_git_for_multiple_developers/

It basically lets you have one shared key for the group of users to access the repo.

Comment: Let me explain my problem in detail. I have a single git instance on a server. I am adding two different projects into that git instance. I need only specific set of users to use one project and another specific set of users for another project.

Comment: I am new to GIT. So i need the SSH key option in detail how it could resolve the issue. If you could provide exact steps would be helpful.

Comment: I hope SSH option is applicable only to a single repository. Are there any other options available to provide access to two different projects inside a single git instance. I want some options without using any tools or framework.

Comment: ok, so projects in one repository, separated by different directories.  For this just two two repositories.  let me do another answer for this.

Comment: i have two different repositories inside a single git instance in different directories. I need to understand the exact steps for permissions both the repositories. Say for example, rep1-proj1 should have x users accessing it and rep2-proj2 should have y users accessing it. x users should not have access to rep2 and vice-versa. if you could please provide us with the exact steps to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated info - two projects in one repository, in different directory trees:

Have two repositories.  There should be little to no additional cost, certainly for a short term (<30 day) approach.  Let git do what it is good for and works simply - repo's with users and don't try and smoosh them together.  You'll waste time and effort you'd be better off spending on other stuff.